# How do you start a sharepoint 2013 list workflow in powershell?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to use powershell to start a list workflow. I found a few sites that give examples for sharepoint 2010 workflows, but only one for sharepoint 2013 workflows [here](http://jesperarnecke.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-management-starting-a-workflow-using-powershell/).

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$sourceWebURL = '<URL>'
$sourceListName = '<List Name>'
$TargetWorkflow = '<Workflow Name>'
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]

#Getting a Workflow manager object to work with.
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spSourceweb)
#Getting the subscriptions
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
#Getting the specific workflow within the list of subscriptions on the specific list. (SP2010 associated workflows basically)
$WF = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spSourcelist.ID) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$TargetWorkflow"}
#Getting a Workflow instance in order to perform my commands.
$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

Foreach($item in $spSourceList){
    #Creating the dictonary object I need to parse into StartWorkflow. This could be most other workflow commands.
    $object = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]'
    $object.Add("WorkflowStart", "StartWorkflow");
    $wfis.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WF, $item.ID, $object)
```

When I enter in the correct values the follow error get's thrown.

```
Cannot convert argument "itemId", with value: "GUID", for "StartWorkflowOnListItem" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert the "GUID" value of type "System.Guid" to type 
"System.Int32"."
At line:23 char:5
+     $wfis.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WF, $item.ID, $object)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://YourParameter.xx/sites/publishing/en"

$workFlowManager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager

$list = $web.Lists["YourParameter"]

$workflowAssociations =
$list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("YourParameter","en-US")

$associationData = $workflowAssociations.AssociationData

$items = $list.Items

foreach($item in $items) { $workflow =
$workFlowManager.StartWorkFlow($item,$workflowAssociations,$associationData,$true)
}

$workFlowManager.Dispose()

$web.Dispose()
```

It works in my SharePoint 2013 farm (starts workflow for all items).

Comment: When I run that code I get the following error

`Exception calling "StartWorkflow" with "4" argument(s): "Value cannot be null."
At line:15 char:28
+ foreach($item in $items) { $workflow = $workFlowManager.StartWorkFlow($item,$wor ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException`

Do you know how I can resolve the error?

Comment: I got it working with 2010 workflows, just not 2013 workflows

Comment: Could post the your function please? It seems you are missing one parameter for the method StartWorkflow(...). Could you double check if the parameters $item, $workflowAssociations and $associationData are not null?

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
Foreach($item in $spSourceList)
```

That's all because of in an $item you got list but not an item :)

try

```
foreach ($item in $sourcelist.Items)
```

The method in second post wont work with 2013 workflows only 2010!